# std::bind with variable function arguments including a callback function with variable arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-functions, stdbind

If I have a function with variable arguments, with one of them being a callback function, how would the bind function for that work?
Current implementation as below:

```
template <typename... Args>
bool CallWithArgs(std::function<void (String&, Args... args)> cbk, Args... args) 
{ .... }
```

The above function is being called from a separate class using a future:

```
bool value = true;
auto f1 = std::bind(&CallWithArgs, rawPtr, _1, _2);
std::future<bool> fut = std::async(f1, cbk, value);
fut.wait();
```

Is there anyway to represent variable parameters in the placeholders of the std::bind function? Running into compile issues with the present implementation.

```
note: template<class _Func, class ... _BoundArgs> typename std::_Bind_helper<std::__or_<std::is_integral<typename std::decay<_Tp>::type>, std::is_enum<typename std::decay<_Tp>::type> >::value, _Func, _BoundArgs ...>::type std::bind(_Func&&, _BoundArgs&& ...)
     bind(_Func&& __f, _BoundArgs&&... __args)

note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘_Func’
```

Comment: Have you considered using a lambda instead? (On second thought: you probably need C++14)

Comment: Is this a purely academic question, or are you trying to get something working? If it's the later, the answer is simple: just use a lambda instead.

Comment: I am trying to get something working. The only issue with using a lambda is that the function with variable args is part of a common library. So making it a lambda and putting it in the class where I am calling it would not be feasible.

Comment: @PK17 It's unclear to me why putting lambda in a class would be less feasible than `std::bind`.

Comment: @eerorika As I mentioned the CallWithArgs fn is part of a common library and needs access to other functions/variable within that common library. And I plan to further allow the support to calling that function from other components/executables. Dont want every component implementing the same fn CallWithArgs as a lambda function.

Comment: Why do you use std::bind instead of just passing the arguments in the capture of a lambda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't use C++14's generic lambdas you can make your own by making a functor.  If you have

```
struct CallWithArgsFunctor
{
    pointer_type pointer_to_call_on;
    CallWithArgsFunctor(pointer_type pointer_to_call_on) : pointer_to_call_on(pointer_to_call_on) {}
    template<typename... Args>
    auto operator()(Args&&... args) -> decltype(CallWithArgs(pointer_to_call_on, std::forward<Args>(args)...))
    {
        return CallWithArgs(pointer_to_call_on, std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    }
};
```

then you can use it in your code block like

```
bool value = true;
std::future<bool> fut = std::async(CallWithArgsFunctor{rawPtr}, cbk, value);
fut.wait();
```

This allows overload resolution to work in the body of the call operator instead of you having to cast the function pointer to the type you want to call.

---

If you can upgrade to C++14 your code would just become

```
bool value = true;
auto f1 = [=](auto&&... args){ return CallWithArgs(rawPtr, std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); };
std::future<bool> fut = std::async(f1, cbk, value);
fut.wait();
```

Comment: Upgrading to c++14 would be nice yes :) But unfortunately that's not possible at this time. Will try your suggestion of using a functor and update here. Thanks!

Comment: @PK17 No problem.  Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks @NathanOliver Your suggestion worked. Also created a separate test file to try out the C++14 way and that works too!

Comment: @PK17 Awesome.  Glad it works for you.  Hopefully one day you can upgrade :)